# Hibernate SessionFactory Error with JPA in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm encountering an issue with my Spring Boot application when trying to create a Hibernate SessionFactory for a JPA entity named Customer. Here's my Customer entity class:

```
package com.flexPerk.flexCore.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Customer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    protected Customer() {}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Customer[id=%d, firstName='%s', lastName='%s']", id, firstName, lastName);
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

However, I'm encountering the following error message:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource 

[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.flexPerk.flexCore.model.Customer]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.flexPerk.flexCore.FlexCoreApplication.main(FlexCoreApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.flexPerk.flexCore.model.Customer]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not instantiate id generator [entity-name=com.flexPerk.flexCore.model.Customer]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.IdentifierGeneratorUtil.createLegacyIdentifierGenerator(IdentifierGeneratorUtil.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.createGenerator(SimpleValue.java:414) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.lambda$createGenerators$1(SessionFactoryImpl.java:413) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.accept(ForEachOps.java:183) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1787) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:596) ~[na:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.createGenerators(SessionFactoryImpl.java:412) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1455) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not fetch the SequenceInformation from the database
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.sequenceInformationList(ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:307) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.getSequenceInformationList(ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.getSequenceIncrementValue(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:568) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator.configure(SequenceStyleGenerator.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.createIdentifierGenerator(StandardIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:224) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown table 'SEQUENCES' in information_schema
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:121) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ClientPreparedStatement.java:972) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.33.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.spi.ExtractionContext.getQueryResults(ExtractionContext.java:49) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.extractMetadata(SequenceInformationExtractorLegacyImpl.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.sequenceInformationList(ExtractedDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

I'm using Spring Boot(3.1.2) with JPA with MySQL and Hibernate for this project. Can someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how I can resolve it?

Comment: Please add the complete stacktrace

Comment: Added the Complete stacktrace

Comment: *Unknown table 'SEQUENCES' in information_schema* Do you have set the correct dialect?

Comment: You are correct. The dialect is Postgresql in my context. Thank you. I changed the dialect to MySQL and it works. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

Comment: "I changed the dialect to MySQL and it works."
You mean this can be closed? Give credit to @Jens, then close it.

Comment: @Jens Could you please post this as an answer? I can accept it and upvote that answer.

Comment: @Sarangan Have done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message *Unknown table 'SEQUENCES' in information_schema* indicates, that you have set the wrong dialect, because `GenerationType.AUTO` in mysql uses an `auto_increment`not a sequence. So change your dialect to the `MySQLDialect`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have set the correct Hibernate dialect for MySQL in your application.properties :

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect`

[application.properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmTSD.png)

Comment: @M.Deinum Apart from the wrong dialect name, it was the issue